# Unable to call derived class's method in ArrayList initialized to super class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, arraylist

I am learning object-oriented programming through Java and am writing a refrigerator program to practice. Inside my program, there is class Item with two derived classes PerishableItem and LeftoverItem. I created an ArrayList initialized to the Item and added a PerishableItem and a LeftoverItem to the ArrayList. The problem is that I am unable to call methods inside the derived classes that are not in the Item class.

```
ArrayList<Item> itms = new ArrayList<Item>();

itms.add(new Item("apple", 0.45, new Date(1, 1, 2001)));
itms.add(new LeftoverItem("rice", 9.99, new Date(1, 1, 2001), 3));
itms.add(new PerishableItem("yogurt", 4.48, new Date(1, 1, 2001), 5));

System.out.println(itms.get(2).getDaysToExpire()); // error here
```

getDaysToExpire() is the method inside class PerishableItem and not in class Item. It seems like the compiler does not even see the method at all. Thanks!

Comment: Is the method `private`?

Comment: `itms.get(2)` will return an `Item`-typed object (because the list is declared as `ArrayList<Item>`). If `getDaysToExpire()` is not a method on `Item`, then that's why the compiler makes it fail.

Comment: You can have method getDaysToExpire() in Item class. If you have something specific to child classes then you can override getDaysToExpire() method in your derived classes LeftoverItem, PerishableItem.

Answer (score 2):

`Item` should also have the method `getDaysToExpire`() to work... But when you invoke them then the proper `getDaysToExpire`() in the derived class will be dispatched.

Another way is to typecast the `items.get(2)` to `PerishableItem` and then invoke the `getDaysToExpire`, but this is definitely not a good design.

Any item in the fridge will have a expiry date, So, I don't see why not have this method in the Item class also.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is typecasting items.get() to PerishableItem bad? Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @JustinLam Out of many, lets take a simple situation.. if you typecast, then you cannot place any another object in items[2] but PerishableItem. Plus, lets say you removed "rice" from your fridge, then Yogurt will be items(1)... You can use reflection to workaround this, but the proper solution is a neat and well defined Inheritance.